# Stop '=Combine' code at bottom of list/at first blank cell

Tags: excel, vba, string-concatenation

I am attempting to string together TaskID codes with ", " in between each. Current code is below.

I would like the code to stop at the bottom of the active list/at the first empty cell. Also, for the output to not include a ", " after the last active cell.

```
Function Combine(WorkRng As Range, Optional Sign As String = ", ") As String

'Update 20130815

Dim Rng As Range

Dim OutStr As String

For Each Rng In WorkRng

 If Rng.Text <> " " Then

 OutStr = OutStr & Rng.Text & Sign

 End If

Next

Combine = Left(OutStr, Len(OutStr) - 1)

End Function
```

Comment: please format your code properly

Answer (score 0):

You can check emptiness in advance and exit your loop. 
If you cut not one character, but the lenght of your sign-variable you should be fine with no "," at the end.

```
Function Combine(WorkRng As Range, Optional Sign As String = ", ") As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim OutStr As String
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Rng.Text = vbNullString Then Exit For
        OutStr = OutStr & Rng.Text & Sign
    Next
Combine = Left(OutStr, Len(OutStr) - Len(Sign))
End Function
```